# What is the best way to do web scraping from an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, mobile, web-scraping

I am writing an iphone app and I need to scrape about 50+ websites for data.
Does anyone know of any good client-side solutions that I can use ? I dont want to build a backend just for this.

Any pointers ?

Thanks
Rohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your primary focus is the mobile application, and you want to offload the scraping activity to an outside service.

Use a service such as Bobik ( http://usebobik.com ) that provides APIs for scraping data off websites. You can even test your queries for free!

The API is fairly extensive, have a look at http://usebobik.com/api/docs for more information. There's even a SDK available!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is natural to build a small backend web app that takes a query from your phone and does the scraping. It's extremely easy, is not it? Scraping can be done via curl or something.
A web server these days is about 15 lines of code from the scratch.